# Installing MVC3 Futures

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

[The MVC3 page at codeplex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/54306) has a download for MVCFutures but no instructions for installation. Is Futures automatically included in the standard MVC3 RC2 install or does it required separate steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires manual installation - reference the .DLLs and scripts in your projects if you want to make use of them. If you want to use the Display and Editor templates, simply add those folders under the /Views/Shared directory and the EditorFor DisplayFor scaffolding methods will automatically use them depending upon the data type and data annotations of your model fields.

Answer (score 3):

or you can run a simple line [PM> Install-Package Mvc3Futures] on Package Manager Console
check this link for more information.
http://nuget.org/packages/Mvc3Futures